# Need help stopping processes when I change view controllers in swift.

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, storyboard

I am working on an app with multiple view controllers. I have a main menu view controller, game view controllers with a timer and one game over view controller.

Main menu has a button that takes you to game view controller. There is a timer that starts and when it reaches zero it automatically takes you to game over view controller.

The problem is that if I am in the game view controller and decide to go back to main menu the timer continues.

I then get a warning message:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <...> on <...> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

How do I get the timer to stop when I change view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

invalidate the timer before the view disappears:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    timer.invalidate()
    timer = nil
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
```

Comment: I added that code but I removed the timer = nil part because I was getting an error. I have var timer = NSTime() and it said I couldnt do timer = nil. It still works without it. Thanks